# How to restore a ripple wallet, having the security key?

Tags: ripple, security-key, wallet-recovery

If I try to login to ripple.com I get this message

```
Fetching wallet...
Payward  Wallet not found (Username / Password is wrong)
Local browser  Wallet not found (Username / Password is wrong)
```

It might be a bug, but let's assume I actually somehow corrupted my password.

Luckily I still have my security key, but I've no idea on how should I use it to restore my wallet.

Comment: Pls help me, I can't get my secret key from any links with my ripple.com desktop wallet. The links don't work anymore.
Is there any way now to do this

Comment: Sorry, Ripple is no longer on-topic on this site. Please try reaching out to a site that concerns itself with ripple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following [these instructions](http://www.btcpedia.com/create-new-ripple-wallet-with-secret-key/), after clicking on [Create a new wallet](https://ripple.com/client/#/register), you will have the option of using a custom secret key.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2017, Ripple Trade is no longer available.

You will need to create a wallet with another party, [gatehub.net](https://gatehub.net/) is recommended.

You can then import the Secret Key<sup>[1]</sup> like this:
https://support.gatehub.net/hc/en-us/articles/115003257605-Import-Ripple-wallet

After that, you can send funds elsewhere, but note there is a minimum required balance of 20 XRP.

<sup>[1]</sup> **If you don't have your secret key**, you can try and retrieve it here:
https://id.ripple.com/auth/migrate#/register

Comment: what if someone forgot password and wants to recover password from email id?