# How do I restore a Ripple wallet backup?

Tags: ripple, ripple-client

In the Ripple client (as of 0.2.48-2) there is a way to backup a wallet to a text file. How can we use this file to restore a wallet (for example, to a new browser)?

I am aware how to [regain access to my wallet having the secret key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10521/5406), yet, I would also like to reimport the contacts that were stored in my wallet.

Comment: See also [How to restore a ripple wallet, having the security key?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com//questions/10521/how-to-restore-a-ripple-wallet-having-the-security-key) and [How do I backup my Ripple wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9002/how-do-i-backup-my-ripple-wallet)

Comment: I realize that you can use the secret key to recover account access, but the wallet also contains contact information, and I couldn't find a way to back up and reimport to another browser. Also, what's the point of backing up a wallet to a text file if you can't import it again?

Comment: My _guess_ is that they added the backup to file ability with the intention of having a restore ability "real soon now"... but since then they've decided to re-work the whole client login stuff so they've probably (my guess) decided to leave it until the "new" login stuff is ready. Remember Ripple is still beta, which often means not all features are fully complete :(.

Comment: In the mean time: you can use a blob store to get your wallet to a new browser (perhaps even a local one); if you know how to manipulate browser storage you can directly insert the blob into the new browsers store at the correct place; you can use some code that knows how to decrypt the encrypted blob (e.g. JavaScript code from the [ripple client](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-client/) and/or ripple-lib or some [Go code](https://bitbucket.org/dchapes/ripple/src/default/cmd/wallet-recover/wallet-recover.go) I was experimenting with).

Comment: What's this about reworking the client login stuff?

Comment: The "new" login stuff has been mentioned over on the [Ripple forums](https://ripple.com/forum) a bunch of times. The only link I have off the top of my head is to [wiki page by the CTO](https://ripple.com/wiki/User:Justmoon/New_Login) that may or may not be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

This was already asked [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10521/how-to-restore-a-ripple-wallet-having-the-security-key).

> Following [these instructions](http://www.btcpedia.com/create-new-ripple-wallet-with-secret-key/), after clicking on [Create a new wallet](https://ripple.com/client/#/register),
>   you will have the option of using a custom secret key.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Yes, you can use the security key to regain access to the account, but it does not restore the wallet (including the contacts), and does not make use of the exported text file.